Gradle is unable to find my github repository
I put my github repository as a dependency in my build.gradle. I even put down maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } as some things have said to do, and I don't understand why it's not working. Is it something wrong with my repository? (repository) or is it something wrong with my build.gradle file? (build.gradle:
dependencies {
    // To change the versions see the gradle.properties file
    minecraft "com.mojang:minecraft:${project.minecraft_version}"
    mappings "net.fabricmc:yarn:${project.yarn_mappings}:v2"
    modImplementation "net.fabricmc:fabric-loader:${project.loader_version}"

    // Fabric API. This is technically optional, but you probably want it anyway.
    modImplementation "net.fabricmc.fabric-api:fabric-api:${project.fabric_version}"

    modImplementation "com.github.Flamepoint1544:Beyond-Bedrock-1.20.1:v${project.BBversion}"
    
}

and
repositories {
    // Add repositories to retrieve artifacts from in here.
    // You should only use this when depending on other mods because
    // Loom adds the essential maven repositories to download Minecraft and libraries from automatically.
    // See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
    // for more information about repositories.
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

I have tried as many variants and online solutions as I can find and nothing has worked it just keeps telling me that it can't find it.
